# How to create maps intent in such a way that if maps app is not installed on user's device than it should open the maps in a browser?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-intent, maps

I'm  creating an app where a user can tap in a given address (in a `TextView` form)  and it takes the user to the exact location in the Google maps app. I use this code to achieve this :

```
// Creates button view which is connected to a view in the XML layout, which gets triggered on touching the view.
        Button btnLoc = findViewById(R.id.location);
        btnLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Creates an Intent that will load the location of Mycoffee cafe in map app.
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:00.0000,00.0000");
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                startActivity(mapIntent);


            }

        });
```

The problem here is, in case the Google maps app isn't installed in the user's device, the app crashes on tapping the `location` view. So in such a condition, instead of the app getting crashed, what I want to do is either the app should  open any browser and load the location there (in Google maps website) or it should display a toast message asking the user to install the Google Maps app.
How can I achieve this ?

If possible,please share solution for both.

Comment: I believe this link can help you to solve your problem https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started

Answer (score 0):

What you going to do is to check with the packagemanager if the desired app is actually installed, if it is - promote with the values you gave it the Google maps app.
If not, redirect the user to the play store to install it.

```
  private boolean isAppInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed = false;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        app_installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("TAG","Exception :"+e.getMessage());
    }
    return app_installed;
}
```

Send it with

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("com.google.android.apps.maps");
```

so

```
boolean isAppInstalled = isAppInstalledOrNot(uri);
```

then

```
if(isAppInstalled){
// send the lat and long and promote the Google Maps app
}else{ 
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps");
        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Maps not Installed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(goToMarket);
}
```

if you would like to open it in for example browser or any other application that can handle then

```
Intent openNav= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
    .parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="
            + Constants.latitude + ","
            + Constants.longitude + "&daddr="
            + latitude + "," + longitude));
      startActivity(openNav);
```

pay attention to replace the latitude and longitude here aswell.

Comment: THE LINE boolean isAppInstalled = isAppInstalledOrNot(uri); HAS AN ERROR. IT SAYS Required type:
String
Provided:
Uri         CAN YOU PLEASE SOLVE IT?

Comment: Simply change from Uri uri to String uri or in the function use Uri instead of string.